# Truncate product description shopware 6

Tags: truncate, shopware6

Question anyone has an idea how to truncate the product.translate.description

i used the |truncate: 25 but it's not working also the (25) isn't working in the twig file

in the twig file box-minimal.html.twig i have a line called
{{product.translate.description|striptags|raw }}
and it needs to be max 25 chars and then incl some ...

Hope some one can help

regard,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% set description = product.translated.description|striptags|raw %}
{% if description|length > 25 %}
    {{ description|slice(0, 25) }}...
{% else %}
    {{ description }}
{% endif %}
```